# Generating an e4xmi (Application model) for a project that is already created by e3

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have migrated my project to e4 from e3, but I do not understand how to create the application model for an existing project (created using e3). I need to work on e4xmi file in order to create some new menus and parts for my project further. So how do I generate a e4xmi file for my project?

Comment: If you are using 3x compatibility mode you can continue to do so, there is no need to switch to e4.

Comment: You mean It is not possible?

Comment: There is nothing that will do the conversion for you because you can't use many of the e3 classes in a pure e4 RCP. If you have a lot of e3 code stick to using those APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I just want to create a dialog that needs to be popped by an action. The dialog doesn't have much dependencies from e3. I just thought of creating it using application model since I can able to use Dependency Injection effectively for my dialog.

Comment: You can't do dialogs using the application model anyway at the moment. There is an MDialog part but it is going to be redone in Eclipse 4.7 so should not be used. Stick to JFace dialogs.

Comment: I can not use field injection for my dialog, if I stick to JFace dialogs. Again I need to rely on list of listeners for the controls present in the dialog. Any other way to use dependency injection for my dialog though?

Comment: You can use the `ContextInjectionFactory` class to do injection manually

Comment: Yeah you are right. I have used context injection factory to inject fields manually. It works well. Thank you so much greg.